# normed vector space real analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Prove that $\lVert x\rVert = \left(\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}} \lvert x_k\rvert^p\right)^{1/p}$ is not norm for $\ell^p = \{x = (x_k)_{k\in \mathbb{N}} : \sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}} \lvert x_k\rvert^p < +\infty\}$ when $p \in (0,\,1)$.

I've tried to solve it by giving an example of sequences that don't satisfy the triangle inequality.

I would like to get an example, but I could not find one.

Comment: Is the exercise to prove that $$\lVert x\rVert_p := \left(\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}} \lvert x_k\rvert^p\right)^{1/p}$$ is not a norm for $0 < p < 1$?

Comment: yes Exactly @ Afnan Ibrahim

Comment: Let $x = (1,0,0,0,\dotsc)$ and $y = (0,1,0,0,\dotsc)$.

Comment: thanks alot but can you prove that triangle inequlity not satisfied

Comment: Just calculate $\lVert x+y\rVert_p$ and $\lVert x\rVert_p + \lVert y\rVert_p$.

Comment: yes I know that but i could not calculate ∥x+y∥p,I'm sorry for bother you but really i need the ansower if you can calculate it for me thanks alot

Comment: What problem have you calculating $\lVert x+y\rVert_p$?

Comment: I'm study about normed vector space recent so I have not skills to calculate it actually

Comment: but this does not explain you problem. In fact you have finite sums here. It's really not that hard. Have you tried to show that these functionals aren't norms on $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: @DanielFischer: Can you post your comment as an answer?  This question has been reposted, but since no answers are here yet, "close as duplicate" isn't allowed.

Comment: @NateEldredge Done. Close votes may begin.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest example of two sequences $x$ and $y$ such that $\lVert x+y\rVert_p > \lVert x\rVert_p + \lVert y\rVert_p$ for $0 < p < 1$ is

$$x = (1,0,0,0,\dotsc),\quad y = (0,1,0,0,\dotsc),$$

so that $x+y = (1,1,0,0,\dotsc)$. Evidently $\lVert x\rVert_p = \lVert y\rVert_p = 1$, and $\lVert x+y\rVert_p = \text{ something larger than } 2$.